# Returning two aggregates in a single Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been struggling some with Cypher in regards to taking the SUM of two values and finding the difference.  I have these two queries, which find the total sent and the total received of a node:

```
START addr = node(5)
MATCH addr <- [:owns] - owner - [to:transfers] -> receiver
RETURN SUM(to.value) AS Total_Sent

START addr = node(5)
MATCH addr <- [:owns] - owner <- [from:transfers] - sender
RETURN SUM(from.value) AS Total_Received
```

Basically my question is - how do I combine these two separate queries so I can take the difference between Total_Sent and Total_Received?  I have tried multiple start points like so:

```
START sendAddr = node(5), receivedAddr = node(5)
MATCH sendAddr <- [:owns] - sendOwner - [to:transfers] -> receiver, receivedAddr <- [:owns] - receiveOwner <- [from:transfers] - sender
RETURN SUM(to.value) AS Total_Sent, SUM(from.value) AS Total_Received, SUM(to.value) - SUM(from.value) AS Balance
```

But the Total_Received is null!  To me this looks like a pretty simple use case - what the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't combine two queries by just smashing them together like that. :)

To solve this, I suggest you use WITH to separate your query into two parts, like this:

```
START addr = node(5)
MATCH addr <- [:owns] - owner - [to:transfers] -> receiver
WITH addr, SUM(to.value) AS Total_Sent

MATCH addr <- [:owns] - owner <- [from:transfers] - sender
WITH SUM(from.value) AS Total_Received, Total_Sent

RETURN Total_Received, Total_Sent, Total_Received - Total_Sent as Total_Balance
```

HTH,

Andrés

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work - I keep getting 'SyntaxException: excpected return clause' and the arrow is pointing at 'Total_Received, Total_Sent' on the fourth line.  Any idea?

Comment: I would guess you are using a 1.7 version of Neo4j, right? WITH was introduced in 1.8

Comment: Argh yeah... I wanted to wait for a stable 1.8 before upgrading - okay thanks!