# neo4j percentage of attribute for social network

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

How can I calculate the percentage of an attribute for all the connections of a social network?
In this particular sample I would want to calculate the fraudulence of a user by assessing its interactions (call, sms):

```
CREATE (Alice:Person {id:'a', fraud:1})
CREATE (Bob:Person {id:'b', fraud:0})
CREATE (Charlie:Person {id:'c', fraud:0})
CREATE (David:Person {id:'d', fraud:0})
CREATE (Esther:Person {id:'e', fraud:0})
CREATE (Fanny:Person {id:'f', fraud:0})
CREATE (Gabby:Person {id:'g', fraud:0})
CREATE (Fraudster:Person {id:'h', fraud:1})


CREATE
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Bob),
  (Bob)-[:SMS]->(Charlie),
  (Charlie)-[:SMS]->(Bob),
  (Fanny)-[:SMS]->(Charlie),
  (Esther)-[:SMS]->(Fanny),
  (Esther)-[:CALL]->(David),
  (David)-[:CALL]->(Alice),
  (David)-[:SMS]->(Esther),
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Esther),
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Fanny),
  (Fanny)-[:CALL]->(Fraudster)
```

When trying to query like:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE b.fraud = 1
RETURN (count() / ( MATCH (a) -->(b) RETURN count() ) * 100)
```

I see the following error:

```
Invalid input '>': expected 0..9, '.', UnsignedHexInteger, UnsignedOctalInteger or UnsignedDecimalInteger (line 3, column 33 (offset: 66))
"RETURN (count() / ( MATCH (a) -->(b) RETURN count() ) * 100)"
                                 ^
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the percentage of connections to each fraud:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[:CALL|:SMS]->(f:Person)
WITH TOFLOAT(COUNT(*))/100 AS divisor, COLLECT(f) AS fs
UNWIND fs AS f
WITH divisor, f
WHERE f.fraud = 1
RETURN f, COUNT(*)/divisor AS percentage
```

With the sample data, the result is:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| f                        | percentage        |
+----------------------------------------------+
| Node[13]{id:"h",fraud:1} | 9.090909090909092 |
| Node[6]{id:"a",fraud:1}  | 9.090909090909092 |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

This query only needs a single scan of the DB, and is explicit about the node labels and relationship types -- to filter out any other data that might be in the DB.

Comment: Great. Is it also possible to color the nodes in the plot of Neo4j according to the percentage? It seems to only be available in the table view - not in the graph visualization. Also: is `[:CALL|:SMS*1..3]` the right way to target multiple levels? You mention performance: would it be possible to perform 3 types of aggregations (all - like you did, only sms, only phone) in a single pass over the graph as well?

Comment: The neo4j browser UI only allows you to set node coloration by label, not by property value. And, yes, you can use `[:CALL|:SMS*..3]` for paths of between 1 to 3 matching relationships.

Comment: As for the 2 additional types of aggregation, it is not clear what you want. Are you only interested in paths (of up to 3 relationships) where every relationship has the same type?

Comment: More or less: I would prefer not to copy paste the statement above for call or SMS, Call, SMS and run in 3 passes over the graph.

Comment: I see that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269009/returning-two-aggregates-in-a-single-cypher-query outlines how to combine multiple `MATCH` clauses - which should be fine for a start.

Comment: i noticed that `divisor ` seems to be constant for the network and not each nodes degree.

Answer (score 1):

In your `RETURN` section, you invoke a new query : `MATCH (a) -->(b) RETURN count()`.

This is not allowed in Neo4j, you should make a sub-query with the `WITH` keyword for that :

```
MATCH ()-->() 
WITH count(*) AS total
  MATCH ()-->(b)
  WHERE b.fraud = 1
  RETURN toFloat(count(*)) / total * 100
```

Or in your case, because you only want the total count of relationship in your DB, you can make this query :

```
MATCH ()-->(b)
WHERE b.fraud = 1
RETURN toFloat(count(*)) / size(()-->()) * 100
```

**Updates**

- adding `toFloat` on cypher queries,otherwise the division give an interger not a float

Comment: `count()` is throwing: `Insufficient parameters for function 'count'`

Comment: No problem, but this is only considering the direct neighbors. If I instead want to progress (iteratively) into the network of each user - let's assume until a depth of 3. How could this be integrated? Also, the returned results is 0 which seems strange for me.

Comment: Ha of course, the division of two integers is an integer not a float ... I will correct my response

Comment: for your second point, you just have to change the graph pattern like this : `()-[*..3]->(b)`

Comment: This is better, but only returns a scalar value for the whole network, I was expecting to get an individual value for each vertex.

Comment: Yes I was assuming that it s what you were looking for ... Otherwise can you be more precise and what you want ? Can you give an expected result based on your little dataset ?

Comment: See the second answer. This is what I am looking for. Thanks for the initial answer.