# neo4j multiple match aggregations - single pass over graph?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph like
[image]

in neo4j.

```
CREATE (Alice:Person {id:'a', fraud:1})
CREATE (Bob:Person {id:'b', fraud:0})
CREATE (Charlie:Person {id:'c', fraud:0})
CREATE (David:Person {id:'d', fraud:0})
CREATE (Esther:Person {id:'e', fraud:0})
CREATE (Fanny:Person {id:'f', fraud:0})
CREATE (Gabby:Person {id:'g', fraud:0})
CREATE (Fraudster:Person {id:'h', fraud:1})


CREATE
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Bob),
  (Bob)-[:SMS]->(Charlie),
  (Charlie)-[:SMS]->(Bob),
  (Fanny)-[:SMS]->(Charlie),
  (Esther)-[:SMS]->(Fanny),
  (Esther)-[:CALL]->(David),
  (David)-[:CALL]->(Alice),
  (David)-[:SMS]->(Esther),
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Esther),
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Fanny),
  (Fanny)-[:CALL]->(Fraudster)
```

[neo4j percentage of attribute for social network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512635/neo4j-percentage-of-attribute-for-social-network)
allows to easily calculate the fraudulence percentage of a social network:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[:CALL|:SMS]->(f:Person)
WITH TOFLOAT(COUNT(*))/100 AS divisor, COLLECT(f) AS fs
UNWIND fs AS f
WITH divisor, f
WHERE f.fraud = 1
RETURN f, COUNT(*)/divisor AS percentage
```

How can I modify this to use **multiple matches for the different types of relations - but still only require a single pass over the graph**? I.e. have something more efficient than simply calling the following 3 statements:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[:CALL]->(f:Person)
    WITH TOFLOAT(COUNT(*))/100 AS divisor, COLLECT(f) AS fs
    UNWIND fs AS f
    WITH divisor, f
    WHERE f.fraud = 1
    RETURN f, COUNT(*)/divisor AS percentage

MATCH (:Person)-[:SMS]->(f:Person)
    WITH TOFLOAT(COUNT(*))/100 AS divisor, COLLECT(f) AS fs
    UNWIND fs AS f
    WITH divisor, f
    WHERE f.fraud = 1
    RETURN f, COUNT(*)/divisor AS percentage

MATCH (:Person)-[:CALL|:SMS]->(f:Person)
    WITH TOFLOAT(COUNT(*))/100 AS divisor, COLLECT(f) AS fs
    UNWIND fs AS f
    WITH divisor, f
    WHERE f.fraud = 1
    RETURN f, COUNT(*)/divisor AS percentage
```

But rather have something which returns `percentage_total, percentage_sms, percentage_phone` ?

Comment: `UNION` is not an option?

Comment: But that would just concatenate the results and not provide the 3 different columns for a vertex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to keep the results together, you need to chain the queries using `WITH` and pass along the `f` variable for the person. Unfortunately, you also have to keep passing all `percentage_*` variables in all `WITH` clauses, so it gets quite difficult to maintain:

```
MATCH (f:Person)    
OPTIONAL MATCH (:Person)-[:CALL|:SMS]->(f)
    WITH TOFLOAT(COUNT(*))/100 AS divisor, COLLECT(f) AS fs
    UNWIND fs AS f
    WITH divisor, f
    WHERE f.fraud = 1
    WITH f, COUNT(*)/divisor AS percentage_all

OPTIONAL MATCH (:Person)-[:CALL]->(f)
    WITH TOFLOAT(COUNT(*))/100 AS divisor, COLLECT(f) AS fs, percentage_all
    UNWIND fs AS f
    WITH divisor, f, percentage_all
    WHERE f.fraud = 1
    WITH f, percentage_all, COUNT(*)/divisor AS percentage_phone

OPTIONAL MATCH (:Person)-[:SMS]->(f)
    WITH TOFLOAT(COUNT(*))/100 AS divisor, COLLECT(f) AS fs, percentage_all, percentage_phone
    UNWIND fs AS f
    WITH divisor, f, percentage_all, percentage_phone
    WHERE f.fraud = 1
    RETURN f, percentage_all, percentage_phone, COUNT(*)/divisor AS percentage_sms
```

The openCypher project proposed [nested subqueries](https://github.com/petraselmer/openCypher/blob/CIP-nested-subqueries/cip/1.accepted/CIP2016-06-22-nested-updating-and-chained-subqueries.adoc), but this will take some time to make to Neo4j.

Comment: Though the last one should be the first query - and the rest all optional matches i.e. currently, an empty set is returned.

Comment: Good point - I updated the query, with optionals for all three.

Comment: Also one improvement could be to simply aggregate by mean (assuming fraud is 0 or 1 to calculate the percentage more efficiently `avg(f.fraud)` - but I am not really sure how to integrate this into cypher.