# neo4j mean of property for all friends

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Having a graph like:

[image]

```
CREATE (Alice:Person {id:'a', fraud:1})
    CREATE (Bob:Person {id:'b', fraud:0})
    CREATE (Charlie:Person {id:'c', fraud:0})
    CREATE (David:Person {id:'d', fraud:0})
    CREATE (Esther:Person {id:'e', fraud:0})
    CREATE (Fanny:Person {id:'f', fraud:0})
    CREATE (Gabby:Person {id:'g', fraud:0})
    CREATE (Fraudster:Person {id:'h', fraud:1})


CREATE
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Bob),
  (Bob)-[:SMS]->(Charlie),
  (Charlie)-[:SMS]->(Bob),
  (Fanny)-[:SMS]->(Charlie),
  (Esther)-[:SMS]->(Fanny),
  (Esther)-[:CALL]->(David),
  (David)-[:CALL]->(Alice),
  (David)-[:SMS]->(Esther),
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Esther),
  (Alice)-[:CALL]->(Fanny),
  (Fanny)-[:CALL]->(Fraudster)
```

When trying to query like:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE b.fraud = 1
RETURN (count() / ( MATCH (a) -->(b) RETURN count() ) * 100)
```

I want to compute the fraudulence of a user which (as fraud is only either 0 or 1 is defined as the mean of all connected nodes fraud level:

```
MATCH ()--(f)
RETURN f.id, f.fraud, COUNT(*), COLLECT(f) AS fs
```

returns the correct number of friends, but is not able to access these i.e. in the collect statement is only accessing the node itself:

```
╒══════╤═════════╤══════════════╤══════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"f.id"│"f.fraud"│"avg(f.fraud)"│"COUNT(*)"│"fs"                                                                  │
╞══════╪═════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"h"   │1        │1             │1         │[{"fraud":1,"id":"h"}]                                                │
├──────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"f"   │0        │0             │4         │[{"fraud":0,"id":"f"},{"fraud":0,"id":"f"},{"fraud":0,"id":"f"},{"frau│
│      │         │              │          │d":0,"id":"f"}]                                                       │
....
```

I.e. naively calculating the average

```
MATCH ()--(f)
RETURN f.id, avg(f.fraud)
```

will only consider this single node and not the network. **How can I consider the social network of a node instead** (up to a defined depth, i.e. here 1) to improve the original answer of [neo4j percentage of attribute for social network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512635/neo4j-percentage-of-attribute-for-social-network)

## edit

```
MATCH p = ()--()
UNWIND nodes(p) AS f
RETURN f.id, f.fraud, COUNT(*), COLLECT({id: f.id, fraud: f.fraud}) AS fs
```

will return only duplicates of the original node in the list and not the connected nodes:

```
│"f.id"│"f.fraud"│"COUNT(*)"│"fs"                                                                  │
╞══════╪═════════╪══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"h"   │1        │2         │[{"id":"h","fraud":1},{"id":"h","fraud":1}]                           │
├──────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"f"   │0        │8         │[{"id":"f","fraud":0},{"id":"f","fraud":0},{"id":"f","fraud":0},{"id":│
│      │         │          │"f","fraud":0},{"id":"f","fraud":0},{"id":"f","fraud":0},{"id":"f","fr│
│      │         │          │aud":0},{"id":"f","fraud":0}]                                         │
```

## edit 2

```
MATCH p = (source)--(destination)
RETURN source.id, source.fraud, COUNT(*), COLLECT({id: destination.id, fraud: destination.fraud}) AS neighbors
```

is already pretty close - but lacking the `avg` function

Comment: How about using variable length paths, e.g. `MATCH (f)-[*1..2] RETURN f.id, f.fraud, COUNT(*), COLLECT(f) AS fs`?

Comment: That does not help, as `f` regardless of the number of hops still only represents a single node - and not the list of connected nodes.

Comment: Maybe something like `MATCH p = ()-[*1..2]-() UNWIND nodes(p) AS f RETURN f.id, f.fraud, COUNT(*), COLLECT(f) AS fs` would help? (but with more specific node labels and relationship types to restrict the calculation to the relevant part of the graph)

Comment: same problem with: `MATCH p = ()--()
UNWIND nodes(p) AS f
RETURN f.id, f.fraud, COUNT(*), COLLECT({id: f.id, fraud: f.fraud}) AS fs`, i.e. `p` and `f` only reference the single node, and the collect statement seems to collect that same node k-times, where k is the degree of that node. Also see the edit for a representation of the output.

Comment: See the latest edit - when referencing source and destination only the calculation of the `avg` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH p = (source)-[*..3]-(destination)
RETURN source.id, source.fraud, COUNT(*), avg(destination.fraud), COLLECT({id: destination.id, fraud: destination.fraud}) AS neighbors
```

includes the fraudulence defined as the average